# search within an unextracted .zip file

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to use python to search within a .zip file without actually extracting the zipped file. I understand re.search can do searches within files, but will it do the same for files that have yet to be extracted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is using the zipfile module, it allows reading the name list and other meta info from the zip file prior to extracting the content.

```
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('example.zip', 'r')
print zf.namelist()
```

You can read more here about the [Zipfile Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html)